# Does the MD5 change from encryption?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, md5

I have something I've been researching into and I can't find an answer or maybe just understand. When encrypting a file WITHOUT changing the contents does that change the MD5 Sum/Hash of a file? Like a Word file with the same unchanged string of characters being encrypted, does the encrypted file hold the same MD5 Sum as the encrypted Word file?

Comment: Um, how do you encrypt a file while keeping its original content?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @owlstead I think this is programming-related, as it pertains to what happens when you hash files. I suspect that the OP is trying to figure out the interplay between encryption and hashing and wondering whether they can safely encrypt files without the hashes changing.

Comment: @templatetypedef There is no language involved nor a development environment. It's not about program design either. security or crypto would have been better sites, or even superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, encrypting a file should substantially change any hash of a file.

Cryptographic hash codes are constructed such that hashing any two different strings should produce wildly different results, even if there's a close connection between the original strings. For example, the MD5 hash of "hello" is

> 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

while the MD5 hash of "hello?" is

> 3809718a10a0f59bcf6d4939c10fd28d

Encrypting a file should, with good encryption, make the resulting file look statistically random. Consequently, if you were to hash an encrypted file, it should give a hash that's statistically indistinguishable from the hash of a random string. That means that the probability that you should get the same hash output would, roughly speaking, be about 1 / N, where N is the number of possible hash outputs. For even a decently good hash function, this should be astronomically small.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the fact that the two hashes both start with 5 and have a second hex digit that's numerically close is just a coincidence. The hash of 'hello?' is '3809718a10a0f59bcf6d4939c10fd28d'.

Comment: @NickJohnson It's no problem editing in such remarks as it does not change the answer significantly and could clear up some misconceptions. Did this for you.

Answer (score 1):

That depends; if you create the exact same plaintext from the ciphertext (which is the name for the encrypted plaintext) and hash that then the MD5 sum will be the same. If you just hash the ciphertext then the hash will be different.

Cryptographically secure hashes should always be different from each other, even if only a single bit of input changes. Even though there are unlimited messages that hash to the same value, it should be impossible to find another message that computes to the same hash (this is called a collision).

Note that the MD5 hash function is broken. If an attacker can generate the files to be hashed then it is possible to generate two different files with the same hash. So it is very easy to create two programs that do different things but hash to the same MD5 hash. So use a hash function that has not been broken, e.g. SHA-256 or SHA-512 would be considered a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting a file changes the contents that are stored on disk. The MD5 hash of a file's contents does not know (or care) whether it is encrypted or not, it just reads bytes from the disk. Since the bytes are different between plaintext and encrypted, the MD5 hash will be different.